# Generic connection error in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm receiving an error connecting to a table in BigQuery (through the browser console).

The error is Query Failed
Error: Connection error. Please try again.

Is there any way I can see what's causing it?  The project ID is 153625559528 and the table is resultsFullHistory.

Comment: Still having a problem accessing this table - this is affecting a live website.  Is there any way I can get to the bottom of what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a bug in BigQuery. We've got a fix, but it won't be available until next week. I'm looking into a temporary fix that should work around the issue and can hopefully have something for you by end of today.

Comment: The quick workaround turned out not to work correctly. Is there any chance you can export the table to json and re-import it? If you add tigani@ or jcondit@ as writers to your dataset, we would be happy to do it (where @ is at google.com). Your queries are causing some availability issues, and we'd like to resonve this asap.

Comment: Sure, I've done that now.  I can query all tables except resultsFullHistory - in fact I can now do some limited querying on that table as well but it still hits issues when trying to query the whole table.

Comment: If you export it / reimport it, can you replace the table with the imported version? (is there a better way we can contact you? Can you send an e-mail to jcondit and tigani)?